# Extraer informacion de Viviendas y Poblacion--Python

Tags: python, web, selenium

Estoy realizando un proyecto que consta de extraer el numero de viviendas y poblacion por AGEB en varios municipos de N.L de la pagina de la INEGI pero para poder extraer la informacion se tiene que dibujar el contorno del AGEB manualmente y el mapa no tiene opciones para inspeccionar elementos, ni hay una opcion para automatizar los trazos via HTML, he estado investigando en varios foros, google y en las paginas de la INEGI pero no  he encontrado una solucion para extraer esa informacion, Si me pudieran ayudar  o si saben de algun otro modo/pagina de poder extraer esta informacion estaria muy agradecido.

-----CODIGO-----

```
from selenium import webdriver #Se importa  webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys #Se importa Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains #Se importa ActionChains
import time #Se import Time


driver = webdriver.Chrome() #Se declara  en que navegador se va a correr el programa
driver.maximize_window() #Se maximiza la pagina
actions = ActionChains(driver)
pagina = driver.get("http://www.beta.inegi.org.mx/app/mapa/espacioydatos/")#Se manda a  llamar la liga



driver.find_element_by_id("search-text").send_keys("san pedro garza garcia") # Se busca el campo de busqueda y se agrega un texto a este

boton_de_busqueda = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='search-button']")#Se busca el boton de buscar
actions.double_click(boton_de_busqueda)#Se simula un doble click sobre el boton de buscar
actions.double_click(boton_de_busqueda)#Se simula un doble click sobre el boton de buscar
actions.perform()#Se acciona la serie de eventos  "actions"
actions.reset_actions() #Borra las acciones guardadas

#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='imgMensaje']").click()
time.sleep(35)#ponemos en sleep el proceso para que se cargue la informacion que mandamos a buscar


#-----------------------SE GENERA EL ZOOM NECESARIO PARA ACCEDER AL FILTRO DE OS AGEBS-------------------------#
mapa = driver.find_element_by_id("map2D") #Se almacena el Tag del mapa en una variable para ser manipulada
actions.drag_and_drop_by_offset(mapa,50,0)#Se centra el mapa
actions.move_by_offset(50,0) #Se mueve el cursor para que no se de click en la informacion del municipio que se esta buscando
actions.double_click(mapa) #Se simula un doble click para "Zoom in"
time.sleep(1)#Hacemos intervalos de un segundo para llevar un orden de clicks
actions.double_click(mapa)#Se simula un doble click para "Zoom in"
time.sleep(1)#Hacemos intervalos de un segundo para llevar un orden de clicks
actions.double_click(mapa)#Se simula un doble click para "Zoom in"
time.sleep(1)#Hacemos intervalos de un segundo para llevar un orden de clicks
actions.drag_and_drop_by_offset(mapa,-300,0) #Se centra el mapa en el municipio seleccionado
time.sleep(1)#Hacemos intervalos de un segundo para llevar un orden de clicks
actions.perform()#Se acciona "accions"
actions.reset_actions() #Se borran las acciones almacenadas

time.sleep(10)
#driver.quit() #Se cierra la pagina

#-----------------------SE BORRAN FILTROS SOBRANTES Y SE AGREGA EL FILTRO DE AGEB-------------------------#
driver.find_element_by_id("linkcapasactivas").click() #Se seleccion la pestaña capas activas
time.sleep(1)#Hacemos intervalos de un segundo para llevar un orden de clicks
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_1384Active").click()#Generamos un click en Vialidades para quitar su filtro sobre el mapa
time.sleep(1)#Hacemos intervalos de un segundo para llevar un orden de clicks
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_1206Active").click()#Se acciona un click en Carreteras para quitar su filtro sobre el mapa
time.sleep(1)#Hacemos intervalos de un segundo para llevar un orden de clicks
driver.find_element_by_id("linkVisualizar").click()#Se genera un click sobre la pestaña Visualizar
time.sleep(1)#Hacemos intervalos de un segundo para llevar un orden de clicks
driver.find_element_by_id("LabelGeografia").click()#Se genera un click en la opcion Geografia para desplegar sus opciones
time.sleep(1)#Hacemos intervalos de un segundo para llevar un orden de clicks
driver.find_element_by_id("checkbox_1165").click()#Se acciona un click en la casiila de AGEBS para activar su filtro
time.sleep(1)#Hacemos intervalos de un segundo para llevar un orden de clicks


#-----------------------TRAZADOS DE AGEBS-------------------------#
driver.find_element_by_id("btnPolygon").click()

actions.move_by_offset(0, 100)
actions.click(map)
time.sleep(1)#Hacemos intervalos de un segundo para llevar un orden de clicks
actions.move_by_offset(100,-100)
actions.click(map)
time.sleep(1)#Hacemos intervalos de un segundo para llevar un orden de clicks
actions.move_by_offset(-100,0)
actions.click(map)
time.sleep(1)#Hacemos intervalos de un segundo para llevar un orden de clicks

driver.quit()
```